# Number precision change on select option

Tags: javascript, html

When I select option to 3 for example round number by 3 after comma. Can someone help me?

```js
function LengthConverter(valNum) {
  document.getElementById("outputMeters").innerHTML = (valNum * 1.8) + 32;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label>Celsius</label>
  <input autofocus id="inputFeet" type="number" placeholder="Celsius" oninput="LengthConverter(this.value)" onchange="LengthConverter(this.value)">

  <td class="precision">Precision:
    <select name="precision" id="opt" size="1" onchange="update()">
      <option value="1">0</option>
      <option value="10">1</option>
      <option value="100">2</option>
      <option selected="selected" value="1000">3</option>
      <option value="10000">4</option>
      <option value="100000">5</option>
      <option value="1000000">6</option>
      <option value="10000000">7</option>
      <option value="100000000">8</option>
      <option value="1000000000">9</option>
      <option value="1000000000000">12</option>
      <option value="1000000000000000">15</option>
      <option value="1000000000000000000">18</option>
    </select>
  </td>

</p>
<p>Fahrenheit: <span id="outputMeters"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this helper function

```
function round(x, n) { 
  return parseFloat(Math.round(x * Math.pow(10, n)) / Math.pow(10, n)).toFixed(n);
}
```

It is a combination of `Math.round` and `toFixed()` which fills up zeros.

```html
<p>
    <label>Celsius</label>
    <input autofocus id="inputFeet" type="number" placeholder="Celsius" oninput="LengthConverter()" onchange="LengthConverter()">
    
   <td class="precision">Precision: <select name="precision" id="opt" size="1"  onchange="LengthConverter()">
      <option value="1">0</option>
      <option value="10">1</option>
      <option value="100">2</option>
      <option selected="selected" value="1000">3</option>
      <option value="10000">4</option>
      <option value="100000">5</option>
      <option value="1000000">6</option>
      <option value="10000000">7</option> 
      <option value="100000000">8</option>
      <option value="1000000000">9</option>
      <option value="1000000000000">12</option>
      <option value="1000000000000000">15</option>
      <option value="1000000000000000000">18</option>
  </select></td>
    
  </p>
  <p>Fahrenheit: <span id="outputMeters"></span></p>
  
  <script>
  function LengthConverter() {
    var inputFeet = document.getElementById("inputFeet").value;
    var opt = document.getElementById("opt").value.length;
    document.getElementById("outputMeters").innerHTML = round((inputFeet * 1.8) + 32, --opt);
  }
  
  function round(x, n) { 
    return parseFloat(Math.round(x * Math.pow(10, n)) / Math.pow(10, n)).toFixed(n);
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: this is good but can you make this that it will change(update) result immediately

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

`toFixed()` is your friend. It will also handle rounding.  Though do note that it returns a string.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Answer (score 0):

Your precision selector is calling an update function that isn't created, so you can get rid of the onchange="update()" . As people are saying use toFixed(), bellow is how you can implement it.

```html
<p>
    <label>Celsius</label>
    <input autofocus id="inputFeet" type="number" placeholder="Celsius" oninput="LengthConverter(this.value)" onchange="LengthConverter(this.value)">
    
   <td class="precision">Precision: <select name="precision" id="opt" size="1">
      <option value="0">0</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option selected="selected" value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option> 
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="12">12</option>
      <option value="15">15</option>
      <option value="18">18</option>
  </select></td>
    
  </p>
  <p>Fahrenheit: <span id="outputMeters"></span></p>
  
  <script>
  
  function LengthConverter(valNum) {
   var percision = percision = document.getElementById("opt").value
   var fahrenheitValue = (valNum*1.8)+32;
    var stringWithPercision = fahrenheitValue.toFixed(percision);
 document.getElementById("outputMeters").innerHTML=stringWithPercision;
    
  }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `toFixed()` method converts a number into a string, keeping a specified number of decimals.

```js
const n = 4.8768;
const res = n.toFixed(2); // res is a string
console.log(res);
console.log(typeof(res));
```

Celsius in Fahrenheit:
`F =  (C x 1.8) + 32`

Add event listeners to the `<input>` (`keyup`) and to the `<select></select>` (`change`).

### Example

```js
let celsius = document.getElementById("celsius");
let precision = document.getElementById("precision");
let fahrenheit = document.getElementById("fahrenheit");

function celsiusToFahrenheit(val) {
  // F =  (C x 1.8) + 32
  return (val * 1.8) + 32;
}

function getResult(precision, val) {
  return celsiusToFahrenheit(val).toFixed(precision);
}

celsius.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  let selectedValue = precision.options[precision.selectedIndex].value;
  fahrenheit.innerHTML = getResult(selectedValue, this.value);
})

precision.addEventListener("change", function() {
  let selectedValue = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
  if (celsius.value) {
    fahrenheit.innerHTML = getResult(selectedValue, celsius.value);
  }
})
```

```html
<section>
  <span>Celsius:</span><input id="celsius" type="text"><span>Precision:</span>
  <select name="" id="precision">
    <option value="0" selected>0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
  </select>
</section>
<section>
  <span>Fahrenheit:</span><span id="fahrenheit"></span>
</section>
```